# MySQL multiple LEFT JOIN returns back duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, left-join

I have a MySQL query which uses `LEFT JOIN` multiple times in order to connect different tables where the `author` is the same. However, when I `echo` out the result it gives me back tons of duplicate rows (actually `32,920`) when I only have 4 rows recorded in the `grouppost` table and about 100 in the other three.

**Table `status`**

```
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+---------------------+
| id | osid | account_name | author | type | data  |      postdate       |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1 | John         | John   | a    | lkjg. | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+---------------------+
```

**Table `article_status`**

```
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
| id | osid | account_name | author | type | data  | artid |      postdate       |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
|  2 |    1 | John         | John   | a    | bcda. |    1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

**Table `grouppost`**

```
+----+-----+--------+--------+------+-------+----------------------+
| id | pid | gname  | author | type | data  |         pdate        |
+----+-----+--------+--------+------+-------+----------------------+
|  3 |   1 | Group1 | John   |    1 | ABCD. |  2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-----+--------+--------+------+-------+----------------------+
```

**Table `photos_status`**

```
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
| id | osid | account_name | author | type | data  | photo |      postdate       |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
|  4 |    1 | John         | John   | a    | abcd. | a.jpg | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+------+--------------+--------+------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

**The expected result would be to join the four rows together and get the `id` from it with the specified names:**

```
+---------+--------+-------+-------+
| stat_id | art_id | gr_id | ph_id |
+---------+--------+-------+-------+
|       1 |      2 |     3 |   4   |
+---------+--------+-------+-------+
```

---

**MySQL query:**

```
$sql = "
SELECT a.id AS art_id
     , g.id AS gr_id
     , p.id AS ph_id
     , s.id AS stat_id 
  FROM article_status AS a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN grouppost AS g 
    ON a.author = g.author 
  LEFT 
  JOIN photos_status AS p 
    ON a.author = p.author 
  LEFT 
  JOIN status AS s 
    ON a.author = s.author 
   AND a.author = 'John' 
   AND g.author = 'John' 
   AND p.author = 'John' 
   AND s.author = 'John'
";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["gr_id"]."<br>"; // returns back duplicate rows
}
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($conn);
```

**Seeking for possible errors:**

*var_dump($result) :*  `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(32920) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

As in the `var_dump` above, `["field_count"]=> int(4)` which is right since there are 4 fields affected in the query. However, the `["num_rows"]=> int(32920)` gives back 32,920 which is completely wrong.

*var_dump($stmt) :*  `object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`

Again, I would like to select all affected rows from `article_status`, `grouppost`, `photos_status` and `status` table where the `author` is the same, like `John` in the example.

Comment: Provide table structures and (some rows) example data place it on sql-fiddle.com or dbfiddle.com.. Als provide a ascii (text formatted) data table which results you expect. For now i votevote this question to be unclear clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I tried your query and got the expected results: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d43b13/2

Comment: A join cannot have a result that's larger than the product of the number of rows in the original tables. Since there's only 1 row in each table, the join can only produce 1 row in the result. There must be more in your actual tables than you've shown here.

Comment: It is just an example of every table to show the main structure. The recorded datas are just for test and I have multiple records with the same name in the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your query should be simplified to the following..

```
SELECT 
      a.id art_id, 
      g.id gr_id, 
      p.id ph_id, 
      s.id stat_id
   FROM 
      article_status a 
         LEFT JOIN grouppost g 
            ON a.author = g.author 
         LEFT JOIN photos_status p 
            ON a.author = p.author 
         LEFT JOIN status s 
            ON a.author = s.author 
   where
      a.author = 'John'
```

you were explicitly re-adding the AND author = 'John' for each of your other joins.  They should have remained with their respective "ON" clause, not grouped at the end.  Also, via Transitive association ex:

```
A = B   and B = C, therefore A = C.
```

If you are already joining on AUTHOR between each respective table, having a single WHERE clause for "a.author = 'John'" will capture all the rest as 'John' too.

As for the duplicates, might it be based on a Cartesian result that you have multiple 'John' records as an author and it is joining to every other ID based on the name instead of what you think you meant to get.

Ex Data.

```
Article Status
id author author_lastName
1  John   A
2  Bill   E
3  John   H
4  Mary   J
5  John   M


GroupPost
id  author  author_lastname
1   Mary    J
2   John    M
3   John    M
4   John    A
5   Bill    E
6   John    H
```

So, just from the above sample of two tables, for each "John" in the Article table, it finds all "John" names in the GroupPost table and would result in

```
Article ID   GroupPostIT
1 (John A)   2 (John M)
1 (John A)   3 (John M)
1 (John A)   4 (John A)
1 (John A)   6 (John H)

3 (John H)   2 (John M)
3 (John H)   3 (John M)
3 (John H)   4 (John A)
3 (John H)   6 (John H)

6 (John M)   2 (John M)
6 (John M)   3 (John M)
6 (John M)   4 (John A)
6 (John M)   6 (John H)
```

Now, take that out to the other tables too and you can see you get more than you expect.  You probably need better "ID" association between the tables than a generic name that would be common.

For example, your GroupPost should have the authorID, not just a name... same with other tables.